# JSON schema property has wider scope than expected

Tags: python, json, jsonschema

I have the following JSON schema (`testschema.json`) that I am testing in Python3.
I keep getting a validation error for property `"alpha"` and I have tried declaring the property in various ways to no avail.

```
{
    "id": "testschema",
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "description": "test schema",

    "type": "object",
    "properties": {


        "traffic_parameters": {

            "properties": {

                "test_type": {

                    "type": "string",
                    "enum": ["AA", "BB"]
                },

                "capacity": {

                    "oneOf": [
                        {
                            "properties": {

                                "min_percentage": {

                                    "type": "integer",
                                    "minimum" : 1,
                                    "maximum" : 150,
                                    "additionalProperties": false
                                },

                                "max_percentage": {

                                    "type": "integer",
                                    "minimum" : 1,
                                    "maximum" : 150,
                                    "additionalProperties": false
                                }
                            },

                            "additionalProperties": false
                        },

                        {
                            "properties": {

                                "percentage_range": {

                                    "type": "array",
                                    "minItems": 1,
                                    "maxItems": 10,
                                    "items": {

                                        "type": "integer"
                                    },

                                   "additionalProperties": false
                                }
                            },

                            "additionalProperties": false
                        }                    
                    ]
                }
            },

            "additionalProperties": false
        },


        "alpha": {

            "properties": {

                "beta": {

                    "oneOf": [
                        {
                            "properties": {

                                "AA": {

                                    "a":   [90, 95],
                                    "b":   [4, 8],
                                    "additionalProperties": false
                                }
                            },

                            "additionalProperties": false
                        },

                        {
                            "properties": {

                                "BB": {

                                    "a":   [100],
                                    "b":   [0],
                                    "c": [0],
                                    "additionalProperties": false
                                }
                            },

                            "additionalProperties": false
                        },

                        {
                            "properties": {

                                "CC": {

                                    "a":   [50],
                                    "b":   [50],
                                    "additionalProperties": false
                                }
                            },

                            "additionalProperties": false
                        },

                        {
                            "properties": {

                                "DD": {

                                    "a":   [0],
                                    "b":   [0],
                                    "c": [100],
                                    "additionalProperties": false  
                                }
                            },

                            "additionalProperties": false
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },

            "additionalProperties": false
        }
    },

    "required": ["traffic_parameters", "alpha"]
}
```

Here is the test JSON (`test.json`) that uses this schema.

```
{
    "traffic_parameters": {

        "test_type": "BB",

        "capacity": {

            "percentage_range": [1,2,3,4,5,6]
        }
     },

    "alpha": {

        "beta": "AA"
    }
}
```

When I validate this using the Python3 `jsonschema` module

```
with open("testschema.json") as schema_file:
    test_schema = json.load(schema_file)
schema_file.close()

with open("test.json") as json_file:
    test_json = json.load(json_file)
json_file.close()

validate(test_json, test_schema)
```

I get an error on the `alpha` property which is similar in structure to `traffic_parameters` which doesn't error.

`jsonschema.exceptions.ValidationError: 'AA' is valid under each of {'properties': {'BB': ...`

Here is the output

```
E
======================================================================
ERROR: test_valid__JSON_against_schema (__main__.SchemaTests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 35, in test_valid__JSON_against_schema
    validate(test_json, test_schema)
  File "/local/tools/PACKAGES/pyhton3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jsonschema/validators.py", line 541, in validate
    cls(schema, *args, **kwargs).validate(instance)
  File "/local/tools/PACKAGES/pyhton3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jsonschema/validators.py", line 130, in validate
    raise error
jsonschema.exceptions.ValidationError: 'AA' is valid under each of {'properties': {'BB': {'a': [100], 'b': [0], 'c': [0], 'additionalProperties': False}}, 'additionalProperties': False}, {'properties': {'CC': {'a': [50], 'b': [50], 'additionalProperties': False}}, 'additionalProperties': False}, {'properties': {'DD': {'a': [0], 'b': [0], 'c': [100], 'additionalProperties': False}}, 'additionalProperties': False}, {'properties': {'AA': {'a': [90, 95], 'b': [4, 8], 'additionalProperties': False}}, 'additionalProperties': False}

Failed validating 'oneOf' in schema['properties']['alpha']['properties']['beta']:
    {'oneOf': [{'additionalProperties': False,
                'properties': {'AA': {'a': [90, 95],
                                      'additionalProperties': False,
                                      'b': [4, 8]}}},
               {'additionalProperties': False,
                'properties': {'BB': {'a': [100],
                                      'additionalProperties': False,
                                      'b': [0],
                                      'c': [0]}}},
               {'additionalProperties': False,
                'properties': {'CC': {'a': [50],
                                      'additionalProperties': False,
                                      'b': [50]}}},
               {'additionalProperties': False,
                'properties': {'DD': {'a': [0],
                                      'additionalProperties': False,
                                      'b': [0],
                                      'c': [100]}}}]}

On instance['alpha']['beta']:
    'AA'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.007s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

Does anyone know why this is and how to fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to shorten the schema to just enough to reproduce the validation failure:

```
{
    "id": "testschema",
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "description": "test schema",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "alpha": {
            "properties": {
                "beta": {
                    "oneOf": [
                        {
                            "properties": {
                                "AA": {
                                    "a":   [90, 95],
                                    "b":   [4, 8],
                                    "additionalProperties": false
                                }
                            },
                            "additionalProperties": false
                        },
                        {
                            "properties": {
                                "BB": {
                                    "a":   [100],
                                    "b":   [0],
                                    "c": [0],
                                    "additionalProperties": false
                                }
                            },
                            "additionalProperties": false
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "additionalProperties": false
        }
    },
    "required": [ "alpha" ]
}
```

The error indicates failure to validate the `oneOf` constraint, because the `"AA"` validates successfully against every schema listed inside the `oneOf`, and `oneOf` demands that it must match one and only one.

Why does the `"AA"` validate against every schema?  The root cause is that the schemas do not specify `"type"` information for every schema listed inside the `oneOf`.  As explained [here](http://grokbase.com/t/gg/json-schema/156bb8cc78/default-type), if there is no `"type"` specified for a schema, then potentially any valid JSON of any type will match against that schema.  To fix this, we need to add the missing `"type"` constraints.

From looking at the schema and JSON sample, I'm not certain what you want to achieve.  The schema seems to be describing `"AA"`, `"BB"`, etc. as nested objects, but the JSON sample seems to show that `"beta"` just needs to be mapped to a string value like `"AA"`.

If the JSON sample is the correct source of information, you could fix the problem with a schema like this.

```
schema = json.loads('''
{
    "id": "testschema",
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "description": "test schema",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "alpha": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "beta": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "enum": [ "AA", "BB", "CC", "DD" ]
                }
            },
            "additionalProperties": false
        }
    },
    "required": [ "alpha" ]
}
''')

# valid
validate(json.loads('''
{
    "alpha": {
        "beta": "AA"
    }
}
'''), schema)

# valid
validate(json.loads('''
{
    "alpha": {
        "beta": "BB"
    }
}
'''), schema)

# invalid
validate(json.loads('''
{
    "alpha": {
        "beta": "ZZ"
    }
}
'''), schema)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 7, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/jsonschema/validators.py", line 541, in validate
    cls(schema, *args, **kwargs).validate(instance)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/jsonschema/validators.py", line 130, in validate
    raise error
jsonschema.exceptions.ValidationError: u'ZZ' is not one of [u'AA', u'BB', u'CC', u'DD']

Failed validating u'enum' in schema[u'properties'][u'alpha'][u'properties'][u'beta']:
    {u'enum': [u'AA', u'BB', u'CC', u'DD'], u'type': u'string'}

On instance[u'alpha'][u'beta']:
    u'ZZ'
```

OTOH, if your goal is for `"AA"`, `"BB"`, etc. to be sub-objects, then you can fix it by changing the schema to something like this.

```
schema = json.loads('''
{
    "id": "testschema",
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "description": "test schema",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "alpha": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "beta": {
                    "oneOf": [
                        {
                            "type": "object",
                            "properties": {
                                "AA": {
                                    "type": "object",
                                    "properties": {
                                        "a": {
                                            "type": "array"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            "additionalProperties": false
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "object",
                            "properties": {
                                "BB": {
                                    "type": "object",
                                    "properties": {
                                        "b": {
                                            "type": "array"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            "additionalProperties": false
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "additionalProperties": false
        }
    },
    "required": [ "alpha" ]
}
''')

# valid
validate(json.loads('''
{
    "alpha": {
        "beta": {
            "AA": {
                "a": [ 1 ]
            }
        }
    }
}
'''), schema)

# valid
validate(json.loads('''
{
    "alpha": {
        "beta": {
            "BB": {
                "b": [ 1 ]
            }
        }
    }
}
'''), schema)

# invalid
validate(json.loads('''
{
    "alpha": {
        "beta": {
            "ZZ": {
                "z": [ 1 ]
            }
        }
    }
}
'''), schema)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 11, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/jsonschema/validators.py", line 541, in validate
    cls(schema, *args, **kwargs).validate(instance)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/jsonschema/validators.py", line 130, in validate
    raise error
jsonschema.exceptions.ValidationError: {u'ZZ': {u'z': [1]}} is not valid under any of the given schemas

Failed validating u'oneOf' in schema[u'properties'][u'alpha'][u'properties'][u'beta']:
    {u'oneOf': [{u'additionalProperties': False,
                 u'properties': {u'AA': {u'properties': {u'a': {u'type': u'array'}},
                                         u'type': u'object'}},
                 u'type': u'object'},
                {u'additionalProperties': False,
                 u'properties': {u'BB': {u'properties': {u'b': {u'type': u'array'}},
                                         u'type': u'object'}},
                 u'type': u'object'}]}

On instance[u'alpha'][u'beta']:
    {u'ZZ': {u'z': [1]}}

# invalid
validate(json.loads('''
{
    "alpha": {
        "beta": {
            "AA": {
                "a": [ 1 ]
            },
            "BB": {
                "b": [ 1 ]
            }
        }
    }
}
'''), schema)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 14, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/jsonschema/validators.py", line 541, in validate
    cls(schema, *args, **kwargs).validate(instance)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/jsonschema/validators.py", line 130, in validate
    raise error
jsonschema.exceptions.ValidationError: {u'AA': {u'a': [1]}, u'BB': {u'b': [1]}} is not valid under any of the given schemas

Failed validating u'oneOf' in schema[u'properties'][u'alpha'][u'properties'][u'beta']:
    {u'oneOf': [{u'additionalProperties': False,
                 u'properties': {u'AA': {u'properties': {u'a': {u'type': u'array'}},
                                         u'type': u'object'}},
                 u'type': u'object'},
                {u'additionalProperties': False,
                 u'properties': {u'BB': {u'properties': {u'b': {u'type': u'array'}},
                                         u'type': u'object'}},
                 u'type': u'object'}]}

On instance[u'alpha'][u'beta']:
    {u'AA': {u'a': [1]}, u'BB': {u'b': [1]}}
```

Either way, the important thing is to make sure `"type"` information is specified where necessary.

Comment: Thanks just what I needed. I also wanted to set the schema to certain fixed values for each of 'a' and 'b', so that the user may choose one set. 

I have done this with; "items": {
                                        
                                            "spot": [90, 95],
                                            "wide": [4, 8],
                                            "global": [0.2, 0.6]
                                        }


I think my main confusion is what constitutes an object. But the link you provided helps, thanks again.

Comment: For example, if I had "number_of_scripts": { "type": "integer", "minimum" : 1, "maximum" : 200, "additionalProperties": false } would you advise adding "type": "object" and "properties" or will this suffice?

Comment: I have posted the second part of what I am trying to do as a separate question; 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45281533/how-do-you-assign-a-whole-object-along-with-its-properties-in-json